# Terraria Android NPC refuse to talk

Tags: android, terraria-mobile

I have this issue today. Yesterday it was fine I could talk with them. Today when I clicked on nurse chest menu opened up. So to talk to the nurse I replaced the chest far away. Now when I tap on nurse she won't respond. I tried tapping on other npc (including demolisher in the screen shot) they don't respond for shop menu. What can be done in this situation?[image]

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: Nope. I will try it now

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work

Comment: I never played the mobile version of terraria, but could it be that you are accidentally interacting with different things? For example, if you have your hammer equipped, you might be chipping the wall instead. Try with an empty hand, and try different NPCs

Comment: If u see the screenshot carefully I am not holding anything while trying to interact

Comment: My mistake. Again, I do not play the mobile version. What do you mean by NPCs not responding in the shop menu? Can you successfully talk to the demolisher?

Comment: No dialogue box is displayed. When it should have been displayed

Comment: Did you hear the sound that plays when interacting with an NPC? If not, then it is not within my knowledge unfortunately

Comment: In mobile version no such sound (heard in PC) is played.

Comment: When you say you tried turning it off and on, was this the phone, or the game? Android id not designed to close programs, so if you close an app, it generally just continues running in the background.

Comment: today ,a blood moon event occurred. 2 zombies killed the guide. after few minutes at morning when the guide arrived I was able to talk to him. so should I let other npcs die and then spawn again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting the NPC be killed by mob. And when it spawned next time I was able to talk to them. So respawnning them solves the problem.